# Program for PC Technicians

Tags: windows, programming

I work for a corporation and a downside is we have no single application for diagnosing PCs

What I would like is a local application that can:

- ping a machine and tell me its fully qualified domain name
- gather PC information and display it with one button
- tell me what OU it is in
- tell me what groups the customer has
- let customer click on a box to open our remote support page
- be light ( so maybe it pulls scripts down from a server into a designated folder)
- be able to install applications to another machine on the network
- use some MMC modules such as diskmgmt.msc, compmgmt.msc etc...
- be very modern looking and update able with the times
- be easy on the eyes for us and customers

Can this be done with .Net or a C language?

Comment: *Can this be done with .Net or a C language?* Yes. But that question is off-topic here. Please [edit] your question and make it a request for software recommendations.

Comment: "ping a machine and tell me its fully qualified domain name" - just f.y.i, ping won't do that - you need reverse DNS lookup

Comment: "let customer click on a box to open our remote support page" ... "Can this be done with .Net or a C language?"  ... are you looking for a ready made tool, or planning to program your own?

Comment: There is an extremely compreghsive list of possiblöy useful tools at http://www.slac.stanford.edu/xorg/nmtf/nmtf-tools.html and http://www.pockethernet.com/ looks interesting too

Answer (score 1):

There is [GRR](https://github.com/google/grr/blob/master/README.md) which consists of a small lightweight client on each of the client machines plus a technicians server installation.

From the Read Me.

> README.md:
>
> GRR Rapid Response is an incident response framework focused on remote live forensics.
>
> GRR consists of an agent (client) that can be deployed to a target system, and server infrastructure that can manage and talk to the agent.
>
> Client Features:
>
> - Cross-platform support for Linux, Mac OS X and Windows clients.
>
>   - Live remote memory analysis using open source memory drivers for Linux, Mac OS X and Windows, and the Rekall memory analysis framework.
>   - Powerful search and download capabilities for files and the Windows registry.
>   - Secure communication infrastructure designed for Internet deployment.
>   - Client automatic update support.
>   - Detailed monitoring of client CPU, memory, IO usage and self-imposed limits.
>
> Server Features:
>
> - Fully fledged response capabilities handling most incident response and forensics tasks.
>
>   - OS-level and raw file system access, using the SleuthKit (TSK).
>   - Enterprise hunting (searching across a fleet of machines) support.
>   - Fully scalable back-end to handle very large deployments.
>   - Automated scheduling for recurring tasks.
>   - Fast and simple collection of hundreds of digital forensic artifacts.
>   - Asynchronous design allows future task scheduling for clients, designed to work with a large fleet of laptops.
>   - Ajax Web UI.
>   - Fully scriptable IPython console access.

I believe that both are free open source and cross platform the only thing that doesn't match your question is the are python based not .net or C# but that does help for the cross platform side of things.